# Click on product directs to cart

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a product loop on category page.

I need when the user clicks on a product he will **not** be directed to the product page, but rather to the cart page.

Two things will happen simultaneously:

1. the product will be added to the cart; and
2. The user will be directed to the cart page

What is the best way to achieve this?

1. Change this href?

   ```
   <?php the_permalink(); ?>
   ```
2. Replace the a tag of the product with an a tag of the add-to cart loop?

   ```
    <?php
      $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'product',
      'stock' => 1,
      'posts_per_page' => 4,
      'orderby' =>'date',
      'order' => 'DESC' );
      $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
      while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global    $product; ?>
      <div class="span3">
      <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"      title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
      <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo    get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img   src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="My Image Placeholder"   width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>
      <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
      <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>   </span>
      </a>
      <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
      </div><!-- /span3 -->
     <?php endwhile; ?>
     <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
   ```

#### Update:

Adding this URL `href=”http://yourdomain.com/cart/?add-to-cart=25` to the add-to-cart button href, will add one simple product to cart and redirect to Cart Afterwards.

https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/

I still need that click on a product will make this happen and, not click on the add-to-cart button.

Comment: Do you want the link to take the user directly to the Cart, or do you want the product to be added to the cart first, then for the user to be redirected to the cart page?

Comment: Hi Kirk, yes I want that the a link  that contains a product in the HTML ,will take the user directly to the Cart......<a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will do two things:

1. Add the product to your cart; and
2. Redirect the user to the shopping cart

The updated line of code:

```
<a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php site_url(); ?>/cart/?add-to-cart=<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
```

Your full code should become:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'stock' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
    'orderby' =>'date',
    'order' => 'DESC'
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); global $product; ?>
    <div class="span3">
        <!-- Line below is changed -->
        <a id="id-<?php the_id(); ?>" href="<?php site_url(); ?>/cart/?add-to-cart=<?php the_ID(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">
            <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="My Image Placeholder" width="65px" height="115px" />'; ?>
            <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?>   </span>
        </a>
        <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>
    </div><!-- /span3 -->
<?php endwhile; ?>
<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Optionally, you could remove the `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()` function completely if you don't want the "Add to cart" button shown.

This example will only work with simple products. Variable products would require the `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()` function to ensure you could select between the available variations for the product.

Comment: excellent !! thank you very much for your time and sharing with me your knowledge:))